How to remove end of string in R having a specific condition, but keep part of condition?
I have a dataset of over 15.000 lines where I want to remove the ending of the string if the condition is a regular expression of the form ([a-z]{1}\\.). How can I remove everything behind the letter, but keep the letter in the resultstring?
Example <- c("12b.1", "12.2", "12", "12az", "155.a.12", "1r.og", "1.7a")

The result should look like this:
[1] "12b"  "12.2" "12" "12az" "155.a" "1r"  "1.7a" 
I have tried it with the stringr package but without success:
> str_replace(fruits, "([a-z]{1}\\.)", "")
[1] "121"    "12.2"   "12"     "12az"   "155.12" "1og"    "1.7a"


look at using the look-behind structure (?<=[a-z]{1})

Look-behind structure means brackets?

google "regex look-behind" for the details - there will be better explanations than I can fit in a comment.

You may use a look behind regex to identify the condition and remove everything from "." to the end of the string.
stringr::str_remove(Example, "(?<=[a-z]{1})\\..*")
#[1] "12b"   "12.2"  "12"    "12az"  "155.a" "1r"    "1.7a" 

Note that str_remove is shorthand for str_replace(string, pattern, "").

Are uou sure the {1} is doing anything given that you did not bound your regex? Eg will this work on abc.q? Ie not change it?

Just tested this and it fails on the example I gave above.

@Onyambu Agreed, but from the OP is there any indication that that construct is possible?  All the provided examples begin as numeric.  If that option was possible, how would you address it?

@PGSA well in that case it will still fail in 12az.1, 12az.1.1 , 12az.a.bc 155.a.betc. Also note that OP specifies the end of string. Meaning yes the construct is possible

Thank you.  What in this reg expression is the look behind functionality? The brackets (), or how is it identified that the dot will be deleted, but the letter not?

Look behind functionality is represented by ?<= so in this case it is (?<=[a-z]{1}). The dot and remaining part to be deleted is \\..* is outside the brackets so they are deleted accordingly.

Using Base R:
sub("(^|[^a-z])[a-z]\\K[.][^.]+$", "", Example, perl = TRUE)
[1] "12b"   "12.2"  "12"    "12az"  "155.a" "1r"    "1.7a"

or
sub("(?<=((?<=^)|(?<=[^a-z]))[a-z])[.][^.]+$", "", Example, perl = TRUE)
[1] "12b"   "12.2"  "12"    "12az"  "155.a" "1r"    "1.7a" 

Using stringr:
str_remove(Example, "(?<=(^|[^a-z])[a-z])[.][^.]+$")
[1] "12b"   "12.2"  "12"    "12az"  "155.a" "1r"    "1.7a" 

if you dont want to use \\K:
This takes into consideration strings such as:
Example2 <- c("d.1", "12az.1","12az.1.a", "12az.a.1")

sub("(^|[^a-z])[a-z]\\K[.][^.]+$", "", Example2, perl = TRUE)
[1] "d"        "12az.1"   "12az.1.a" "12az.a"  


I've not seen \K before - that's very useful.
